# dotnet --environment documentation?

Tags: command-line, environment, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm presently developing with ASP.NET Core 2.2:

```
dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.2.300
 Commit:    73efd5bd87

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.17134
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.300\
```

and running:

```
dotnet myapp.dll --environment=Local
```

will set my IHostingEnvironment to "Local", but I can't find any official documentation on --environment and whether or not it will serve as an override the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable (it appears it does not though).

I have specific need to use this argument in my Program.cs when building a configuration, setting up logging, etc. and do not wish to use ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT in a system wide capacity.

But it appears that within Program.cs I will need to read the argument manually (as well as handle for its absence) because IHostingEnvironment is not set until later and Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") will obviously be NULL.

Of course I still need to handle for if ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is set, and appropriately choose which to use, which is why I need to know how the rest of the framework handles the --environment argument. So I can follow suit.

Comment: Related issue [ASPNETCORE_Environment overrides cmd parameter](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17963).

Answer (score 6):

First, passing `--environment` does in fact override the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable, at least as far as the default configuration setup goes, and assuming you're actually using config to get the value (`IHostingEnvironment` is composed from config, so that counts).

By default, `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder` loads environment variables before console arguments, which is the last config provider included. If you're doing something custom with `ConfigureAppConfiguration` or building your host from scratch, then that may not be the case any longer.

In any case, the actual environment employed by ASP.NET Core comes from config, however the value gets there. What's unclear from your question is 1) whether you're doing something custom that is interfering with the default behavior and 2) in what way you're trying to access and use the environment where it's not working.

Generally, speaking, you want to build the host and then pull `IHostingEnvironment` out of the host's service collection. For example:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();

    var env = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IHostingEnvironment>();

    host.Run();
}
```

However, if you need to access the environment in something like `ConfigureServices`, you need to obviously find another way. For `Startup`, you may actually inject `IHostingEnvironment` and set an ivar, prop, etc. with that in the constructor:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment environment)
{
    Environment = environment;
}
```

It is also possible to build the service collection and pull it out that way:

```
var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var env = provider.GetRequiredService<IHostingEnvironment>();
```

You may still continue to alter the service collection afterwards. Just be advised that with both approaches, you're not technically getting the final state: only services which have already been registered are available, obviously, and alterations to things like config can happen later. However, for something like the environment name, the result should be consistent.

In something like `ConfigureAppConfiguration`, there's an overload that passes a `WebHostBuilderContext`. You can access both `Configuration` and `HostingEnvironment` directly off this object. The same is true for `ConfigureLogging`, etc.

That should cover just about every scenario, I think.

**EDIT**

So, I think I'm finally understanding the problem you're facing. First, you're assuming that the "environment" should be retrieved via literally using `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")` and not understanding why passing `--environment` in the console isn't affecting that. It won't. The "environment" is determined based config, and environment variables, and specifically `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is just one possible source. Passing `--environment` will effect the console argument config provider. The only reliable source of the environment is `IHostingEnvironment`.

Second, I don't think you're adding the additional logging you want in the right place or the right way, or perhaps you simply are unaware of how to get the environment when doing that. If you want it available at before `Startup` is run, then you need to use `ConfigureLogging`, and specifically, you need to pass in the `WebHostBuilderContext` so you can get the environment:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateWebHostBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureLogging(context =>
        {
            // define additional logging providers
            // get environment via `context.HostingEnvironment`
        }).Build().Run();
```

Comment: My issue is that I need to know what environment I'm in prior to building the host, so I can setup and attach the logging to the host (but I also log lines in Program.cs). It appears that I will just need to handle the command-line argument first, fall back on the environment variable, and default to Production if neither exist. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Where are you setting up the logging? Virtually everywhere you can attach additional logging, you have access to the environment, so I'm not really sure what the problem is.

Comment: The logging is setup in the Main function of Program.cs, lines are logged before the hosting is ever setup. The logger itself is configured per environment, and we get the settings from a file, appSettings.%environment%.json, but if ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is not set, using Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") returns null, and using the --environment argument does not fill in that environment variable. So that was part of the confusion. We just need to read the environment manually so we can get the proper config up front. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: See, I think you missed the point. You need to get the environment from IHostingEnvironment, not directly from GetEnvironmentVariable. Pass --environment doesn't set an environment variable; it alters the config, which is used to compose IHostingEnvrionment.

Comment: I think you are focusing too much on hosting side of this. I need to setup and log lines before I even create the host (including things like host.run() throwing an exception). Take a standard console app with no web host as an example. I still have the need to configure the logger per environment. I get that the --environment has nothing to do with the environment variable, but I still need to use it if specified, otherwise fall back on the environment variable, and finally default to Production if neither was found. Then I can configure my logger and log in Main.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I totally understand everything you've stated. I just needed to know the precedence of the argument versus the environment variable, and was surprised I couldn't find any documentation on --environment though I've seen it used plenty of times.

Comment: Yeah, it is odd it isn't documented better, considering how central it is to so many things. However, it is ultimately just based on config, like most everything else. The default order of ops for config is JSON < Environment JSON < Environment Variables < Command Line Args. So, passing environment as a command line arg will override everything else. The `--environment` flag itself isn't so much a flag as literally passing an argument that goes straight into config the `--` would proceed any config setting you want to pass, the `environment` part is the name of the config key.

Comment: The only reason the environment variable is named `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is to prevent collisions with something more generic like `ENVIRONMENT`. The config setup looks for and discards `ASPNETCORE_` prefix if present.